# What does 'Describe the language of this automaton' mean?

Tags: finite-automata

I've been asked to do this as part of an assignment. Here is the automaton:
[image]

I understood it as describing in terms of the 5 tuples so I wrote:

The states are as follows:  Q = {A, B, C}

The alphabet is as follows: Σ = {0,1}

The start state is A

The accepting state is C

The transition function is as follows:

[image]

Is this what is meant by describing the language or am I supposed to answer using different metrics?

Comment: This appears to be copied from somewhere (e.g., https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-following-automaton-give-example-string-accepted-automaton-b-give-example-string--q65868779, https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-following-automaton-give-example-string-accepted-automaton-b-give-example-string--q65079692).  We require you to credit the source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. again. this is not copy-pasted from another site. It is in fact a coursework question from my university.

Comment: If it is copied from coursework you should still credit the source.  Our referencing policy requires that all copied material be credited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of an automaton is the language *accepted* by the automaton, that is, the set of words accepted by the automaton.

Now, certainly, one way of describing the language is as the language accepted by this particular automaton. But the question is asking you to find a simpler description. Here is the set of words accepted by your automaton:
$$
01, \\
001, 101, \\
0001, 0101, 1001, 1101, \\
00001, 00101, 01001, 01101, 10001, 10101, 11001, 11101, \\
\ldots
$$
Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: Yes, they all end in 01? This is a 3 mark question so I'm unsure what to say beyond this

Comment: That's right – the language consists of all words ending in $01$. The DFA is at state $C$ if the current word ends in $01$; at state $B$ if the current word ends in $0$; and at state $A$ otherwise.

Comment: Right, thank you so much!